# Looping to save a range as a pdf file in a new folder created in the current directory

Tags: excel, vba, loops, pdf

I want to save a range of an excel sheet into a pdf file in a new folder created automatically in the current directory (I need to do the same for all excel sheets in the documents)
But each time I run the code there's no file saved or a folder created on my desktop ( the excel file on which I'm working is located in the desktop)
I will be grateful for your help
Thanks
here's the function that I wrote

```
Sub PDF_saving()
    
    Dim tbAllBoxes() As Variant
        'Put all you textboxes into an array
        tbAllBoxes = Array(SuiviConso.Controls("Textbox2"), SuiviConso.Controls("Textbox3"), SuiviConso.Controls("Textbox4"), SuiviConso.Controls("Textbox5"), SuiviConso.Controls("Textbox6"), SuiviConso.Controls("Textbox7"), SuiviConso.Controls("Textbox8"), SuiviConso.Controls("Textbox9"))
        Dim tballLabels() As Variant
        tballLabels = Array(SuiviConso.Controls("Label2"), SuiviConso.Controls("Label3"), SuiviConso.Controls("Label4"), SuiviConso.Controls("Label5"), SuiviConso.Controls("Label6"), SuiviConso.Controls("Label7"), SuiviConso.Controls("Label8"), SuiviConso.Controls("Label9"))
        Dim shAllSheets As Variant
        'Put all your worksheets into an array
        shAllSheets = Array(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet2"), ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet3"), ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet4"), ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet5"), ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet6"), ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet7"), ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet8"), ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet9"))
    
    Dim wbA As Workbook
    Dim lastrow2 As Integer
    Dim strPath, path  As String
    Dim filename As String
    Dim rng As Range
    
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(shAllSheets)
        If tbAllBoxes(i).Value <> "" Then
    filename = shAllSheets(i).Range("A1").Value & Format(Date, "MM-DD-YYYY") & " rapport de consommation " & ".pdf"
    strPath = path & filename
    MkDir strPath
    lastrow2 = shAllSheets(i).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Set rng = shAllSheets(i).Range("A1 : J" & lastrow2)
    rng.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, filename:=ActiveWorkbook.path & filename
    End If
    Next i
    End Sub
```

Comment: What is the problem in above code? Or should someone who is trying to help you really find that out without your input ?

Comment: Well, there is no input
each time I try to execute the code there's no files saved 
The excel file is located in the desktop 
Thank's I will specify the outcome above

Comment: `strPath = path & filename` you have not populated `path`

Comment: SO is about creating code yourself, and not about copying it from some place and then asking why it is not working...  I propose one vote for closing this question!

Comment: @TimWilliams if it is not populated, it will have the default value of the empty string, but better practice is to define that variable need to be defined before use.

Comment: @Luuk - I know that, but it seems the OP did not mean it do be an empty string...

Comment: @TimWilliams i did what you said + i added a code to check if the directory doesn't exist 
``` lang-vba 
path = Application.ActiveWorkbook.path & "\"
strPath = path & filename

Set fsoFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If fsoFSO.FolderExists(strPath) Then
    MsgBox "found it"
Else
    fsoFSO.CreateFolder (strPath)
    MsgBox "Done"
End If
```

Comment: And what happened then?

Comment: @TimWilliams I tried the idea that Luuk told me 
I removed the if condition on the cell value 
I generated the path for the folder 
folders and files are created but files are not situated in the folders

Comment: It's not clear to me exactly what you want to do.  Is the data being exported in the same workbook where the code is running?  What is "current directory" - the one where the workbook with the data is located?  Where is the name of each subfolder coming from?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open your macro
2. Park on the line `For i = 1 To UBound(shAllSheets)`
3. Press 'F9', a red bullet will apprear before this line (=breakpoint)
4. Run your macro, it will break at the line with the breakpoint
5. Use 'F8' and other options from the 'Debug' menu to see what your code does do.

With every step (after pressing 'F8') think about what happened, and why it did happen. What variables are changed, and if they are updated do they have the value that you expect them to have?

After having this done several times you should have a better knowledge about the working of your macro, which makes it possible to ask a better question about this macro.

Suc6 with debugging!

Answer (score 0):

@ Luuk & @TimWilliams, I tried what you told me
I'm really thankful and grateful
now folders are created & pdf files are generated but the files are not included in the folders

```
Dim tbAllBoxes() As Variant
    'Put all you textboxes into an array
    tbAllBoxes = Array(SuiviConso.Controls("Textbox2"), SuiviConso.Controls("Textbox3"), SuiviConso.Controls("Textbox4"), SuiviConso.Controls("Textbox5"), SuiviConso.Controls("Textbox6"), SuiviConso.Controls("Textbox7"), SuiviConso.Controls("Textbox8"), SuiviConso.Controls("Textbox9"))
    Dim tballLabels() As Variant
    tballLabels = Array(SuiviConso.Controls("Label2"), SuiviConso.Controls("Label3"), SuiviConso.Controls("Label4"), SuiviConso.Controls("Label5"), SuiviConso.Controls("Label6"), SuiviConso.Controls("Label7"), SuiviConso.Controls("Label8"), SuiviConso.Controls("Label9"))
    Dim shAllSheets As Variant
    'Put all your worksheets into an array
    shAllSheets = Array(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet2"), ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet3"), ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet4"), ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet5"), ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet6"), ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet7"), ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet8"), ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet9"))

Dim wbA As Workbook
Dim lastrow2 As Integer
Dim strPath, path  As String
Dim filename As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim fsoFSO

path = ActiveWorkbook.path & "/" & "/rapport de consommation"

For i = 1 To UBound(shAllSheets)
    'If tbAllBoxes(i).Value <> "" Then
filename = shAllSheets(i).Range("A1").Value '& Format(Date) '& " rapport de consommation" '& ".pdf"

strPath = path & filename

Set fsoFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If fsoFSO.FolderExists(strPath) Then
    MsgBox "found it"
Else
    fsoFSO.CreateFolder (strPath)
    MsgBox "Done"
End If
lastrow2 = shAllSheets(i).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
Set rng = shAllSheets(i).Range("A1 : J" & lastrow2)
rng.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, filename:=strPath
'End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: `path = ActiveWorkbook.path & "/" & "/rapport de consommation"` you have two `\\` here...

Comment: @TimWilliams what I want is that each PDF file is stored to its folder defined 
Ex: 123.pdf is in the folder 123 
in my case, both folder and pdf file are created but the folder is empty

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```vb
    Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

    basepath = ActiveWorkbook.path & "/rapport de consommation/"

    For i = 1 To UBound(shAllSheets)
        
        filename = shAllSheets(i).Range("A1").Value
        folderPath = basepath & filename
        If Not FSO.folderexists(folderPath) Then FSO.createfolder (folderPath)
        
        With shAllSheets(i)
            .Range("A1:J" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).ExportAsFixedFormat _
                                Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                                filename:=folderPath & "\" & filename & ".pdf"
        End With
    Next i
```